# Angular service call to .Net api controller not working

Tags: angular, angular-services, asp.net-apicontroller

I have one angular solution where service method calls api controller. but it is giving error. Code is given below :

user.service.ts

```
getMonthlyData(date: string): Observable<UserProfile> {
const url = `${this.api.baseUrl}auth/${date}`;
debugger;
return this.api.http.get<UserProfile>(url).pipe(
  map((data) => {
    debugger;
    this.monthlyLeadsCount = data.monthlyLeadsCount ? data.monthlyLeadsCount : "";
    this.monthlyOpportunitiesCount = data.monthlyOpportunitiesCount ? data.monthlyOpportunitiesCount : "";
    this.monthlyAccountsCount = data.monthlyAccountsCount ? data.monthlyAccountsCount : "";
    this.monthlyleads = data.monthlyLeadsList ? data.monthlyLeadsList : [];
    //this.monthlyLeadsCountOfYear = data.monthlyLeadsCountOfYear ? data.monthlyLeadsCountOfYear : "";
    this.loggedUser = data;

    return this.loggedUser;
  }),
  retry(3), // retry a failed request up to 3 times
  catchError(this.api.handleError) // then handle the error
);}
```

AuthController.cs

```
// GET api/auth/{date}
    [AuthorizeSchema()]
    [HttpGet("{date}")]
    public ActionResult<UserProfileModel> GetMonthlyData(string date)
    {
        try
        {
            DateTime date1 = new();
            var result =  repo.GetMonthlyData(date1);
            if (result == null)
            {
                return Unauthorized();
            }

            return Ok(result);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            logger.LogError($"{nameof(Login)}: {ex.Message}");
        }

        return Unauthorized();
    }
```

Here it is not getting call to api controller. Where is it going wrong?

Comment: Are you sending the correct authorization? What is the network log (browser devtools network tab)?

Comment: nothing in network log.

Comment: what do you have in this.api.baseUrl?